# How can I animate a view's hit box?

Tags: android, animation

If I have a button, and I animate it with a simple animation like

```
button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(R.anim.spin));
```

The hitbox of the button doesn't seem to animate with the button - I suppose that the view's bounding area is not changing.

How can I make the button's hit box follow the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:
- Either by updating the Button's layout parameters, which is expensive and causes relayouts
- Or by using the new animation API introduced in Android 3.0